I am using cardService, why addon (testing) takes to run function too long and gives at last error execution maximum time
I have script that works fine as editor add-on but when I am testing as workspace add-on (as a stand alone appscript) the functions takes too long to run, it does what actually planned, but gives error at the end (run time error).
Planning to keep record of made invoice. i would like to get the range values from Invoicing sheet and paste it as a row without a gap between cells to last available row into Broker Invoice and get new invoice number. this script works only when you are in specific sheet to avoid unintended copies. My question is : does always google add-ons works too slow or there is another way to do this function logics, and how to get rid of the run time error?
function saveRecord() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const formWS = ss.getSheetByName("Invoicing");
  const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName("Broker invoice");

  // Check if the active sheet is "Invoicing"
  if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "Invoicing") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Please switch to the "Invoicing" sheet to run the function.');
    return;
  }

  // Get the current ID from H11 and increment it for the next use
  const idCell = formWS.getRange("H11");
  const currentID = idCell.getValue();
  const nextID = currentID + 1;

  // Define the ranges to copy and batch get values
  const ranges = ["N11", "H12", "H14", "E2:H2", "B11:E11", "H15", "B22:C22", "D22:E22", "E27:H28"];
  const fieldValues = [currentID];

  // Collect all values and flatten them
  ranges.forEach(range => {
    fieldValues.push(...formWS.getRange(range).getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== ''));
  });

  // Append the combined values to the "Broker invoice" sheet
  dataWS.appendRow(fieldValues);

  // Update the ID cell with the next ID
  idCell.setValue(nextID);
}

how to get the function to run faster and without runtime error

I just tested your script on the Workspace Add-On I called "Add-on Starter." It works fine on my side.
You should review how you are testing your add-on.

Workspace Add-on Starter
I took the code from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/translate-addon-sample and reduced it to an "MCVE" that does something on the active spreadsheet: shows an alert. This is to have an "Addon Starter". I also replaced the Google Translate logo with the Google Apps Script log.
To test your code, I added a couple of sheets and gave them the required names, commented out one statement, added a call to the saveRecord` function and added this your code to a new .gs. file.
appsscript.json
{
  "timeZone": "America/Monterrey",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Add-on Starter",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/script/apps_script_1x_24dp.png",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#2772ed"
      },
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomepage"
      }
    },
    "sheets": {}
  }
}

Code.gs
const DEFAULT_INPUT_TEXT = '';

/**
 * Callback for rendering the main card.
 * @return {CardService.Card} The card to show the user.
 */
function onHomepage(e) {
  return createSelectionCard(e, DEFAULT_INPUT_TEXT);
}

Get Sheets Selection.gs
/**
 * Helper function to get the text of the selected cells.
 * @return {CardService.Card} The selected text.
 */
function getSheetsSelection(e) {
  var text = '';
  var ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    const range = ranges[i];
    const values = range.getDisplayValues();
    values.forEach(rowContent => {
      rowContent.forEach(value => text += value ? value + '\n' : '');

    });
  }
  if (text !== '') {
    return createSelectionCard(e, text);
  }
}

Create Selection Card.gs
/**
 * Main function to generate the main card.
 * @param {String} inputText The text from the selection.
 * @return {CardService.Card} The card to show to the user.
 */
function createSelectionCard(e, inputText) {
  var builder = CardService.newCardBuilder();

  // Text input section
  var fromSection = CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(CardService.newTextInput()
      .setFieldName('input')
      .setValue(inputText)
      .setTitle('Selection')
      .setMultiline(true));

    fromSection.addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet()
      .addButton(CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Get Selection')
        .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('getSheetsSelection'))
        .setDisabled(false)))


  builder.addSection(fromSection);

  //Buttons section
  builder.addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet()
      .addButton(CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Do something')
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
        .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('doSomething'))
        .setDisabled(false))
      .addButton(CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Clear')
        .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('clearText'))
        .setDisabled(false))));

  return builder.build();

}

/**
 * Helper function to clean the text.
 * @return {CardService.Card} The card to show to the user.
 */
function clearText(e) {
  return createSelectionCard(e, DEFAULT_INPUT_TEXT);
}

Do Something.gs
function doSomething() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Doing something');
}

As mentioned above, to test the saveRecord function from the question, I added it to a new .gs file, and changed the Do Something.gs file as follows:
function doSomething() {
  // SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Doing something');
  saveRecord();
}

Then I opened the add-on in the test spreadsheet and clicked on Do something. As mentioned on top of this answer, the saveRecord function in the context of my Add-on Starter works fine.
Resources

Testing Google Workspace Add-ons


thank you for the look up into the script! script was working perfect on editor appscript editor part when it became stand alone addon for testing. some parts work some parts does not ( i think it got mood ai;) ). but all of them even working gives runtime error : Exceeded maximum execution time! here 4 parts in logic about exect sheet, range find and pasting as order, than adding id value than gives success! but here it does copy paste the range only with giving error in the card. dont know how to remove that error and what is making to get that kinda error

@MaxYusupov, I don't understand what you mean by "here". Regarding how to remove the error you might need to "split" the problem into smaller parts. I hope that the "Workspace Add-On Starter" included in my answer helps you to do that. If not, please post a follow-up question, including your own "Workspace Add-on Starter" and the steps you followed to test it. In other words, create a [mcve]. P.D. I'm a mentor in Codementor, my SO user profile includes the link to my profile on that platform, but I'm adding it here for your convenience https://www.codementor.io/@rbn
